# How can you prove that $\sin$ function (as the quotient of opposite side and hypotenuse length of a given triangle) is well defined?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given a line (starting from 0), there are lots of hypotenuses distances to choose without changing "the angle". How can you show that the quotient is always the same?

An as a follow up, how can you define the inverse? In the definition there is no number at all to start with (we say angle as we coud say the hypotenuse line) how do we manage to map "the line" or "the angle" to a number between 0 and 2PI, when defining the inverse?

Comment: If you imagine the angle at the origin in the $xy$-plane, then we can use coordinates.  Since it is a right triangle, we can label the points of the triangle $(0, 0)$, $(x, 0)$, and $(x, y)$.  The slope of the hypotenuse is $\frac{y}{x}$.  Any similar triangle has to have the same slope.

Comment: I had this same thought at some point and realized it's because similar triangles guarantee that all corresponding angles are the same and ratios of corresponding sides are equal.

Comment: Why the slope $y/x$ is the same in all similar triangles?

Comment: The question is why $y/x$ and $y/h$ and $x/h$ are the same in all right triangles with the same "angle"? Why is sin, cos, tan well defined?

Comment: And how is it possible to map similar right triangles to reals between 0 and $2\pi$  creating the concept of numerical angle...